# Shortest paths in Alexandrov spaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Let $X$ be an Alexandrov space with curvature bounded from below (if necessary, $X$ might be assumed to be finite dimensional or even compact).

**Question 1.** Is it true that every point of $X$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that any two points from $U$ can be connected by at most one shortest path (which does not have to be contained in $U$)?

**Question 2.** In the previous question, can one choose $U$ to be geodesically convex, i.e.
for any two points from $U$ any shortest path between them (if it is not unique) is contained in $U$?

A reference would be helpful.

Remark. Of course, if $X$ is a smooth Riemannian manifold then the answers to both questions are 'yes'.

Comment: I am afraid, the vertex $p$ of the cone $X$ over the circle of length less than $2\pi$ has no such neighborhood $U$.

Comment: @valeri why don't you make this an answer ?

Comment: @Thomas Richard May be Semyon Alesker means that the curvature is bounded from above? Then the answer might be different.

Comment: @valeri Thank you! I think this is the final answer.

Comment: @semyonalesker You are welcome! Than I post it as an answer.

Comment: @valeri is right that an upper bound on the curvature implies a positive answer to question 1, because one can construct triangles of "arbitrary fatness" from non-unique shortest paths between two points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Counterexample: the vertex p of the cone X over the circle of length less than 2π has no such neighborhood U.